# laravel js, viewing [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to get "Sisa" value form (Bayar - Diterima = sisa) but i got some error
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/transaksi-detail/loadform/0/500000/[object%20HTMLInputElement]](http://127.0.0.1:8000/transaksi-detail/loadform/0/500000/%5Bobject%20HTMLInputElement%5D) 404 (Not Found)
[image]

my view

```
function loadForm(diskon = 0) {
  $('#total').val($('.total').text());
  $('#total_item').val($('.total_item').text());

  $.get(`{{ url('transaksi-detail/loadform') }}/${diskon}/${$('.total').text()}/${diterima}`)
    .done(response => {
      $('#totalrp').val('Rp. '+ response.totalrp);
      $('#bayarrp').val('Rp. '+ response.bayarrp);
      $('#bayar').val(response.bayar);
      $('.tampil-bayar').text('Rp. '+ response.bayarrp);
    })
    .fail(errors => {
      alert('Tidak dapat menampilkan data');
      return;
    })
}
```

loadForm controller

```
public function loadForm($diskon = 0, $total, $diterima){
    $bayar      = $total - ($diskon / 100 * $total);
    $kembali    = ($diterima != 0) ? $diterima - $bayar : 0;
    $data       = [
        'totalrp'   => format_uang($total),
        'bayar'     => $bayar,
        'bayarrp'   => format_uang($bayar),
        'kembalirp' => format_uang($kembali)
    ];

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

my route

```
Route::get('transaksi-detail/loadform/{diskon}/{total}/{diterima}' [PenjualanDetailController::class, 'loadForm'])->name('transaksi-detail.load_form');
```

Comment: Try changing the last part of the url to `${diterima.value}`

Comment: like this? $.get({{url('transaksidetail/loadform')}}/${diskon}/${$('.total').text()}/${diterima.value}) i got some error http://127.0.0.1:8000/transaksi-detail/loadform/0/535000/ 500 (internal server error)

Comment: It looked like diterima was an input element rather than its value, but maybe it’s something else.  Where is the declaration of the diterima variable?